# Multiple capistrano deployments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

At least one of these tasks/steps are in the wrong order and I can't figure out which one.

```
after "deploy",                 "deploy:migrations"
after "deploy:update",          "newrelic:notice_deployment"
after "deploy:setup",           "deploy:db:setup"   unless fetch(:skip_db_setup, false)
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:db:symlink"
after "deploy:migrations",      "deploy:cleanup"
after "deploy:create_symlink",  "deploy:restart_workers"
```

Can the order of tasks be found somewhere? :)

This is the order of events, these things really gives me a headache!

```
cap staging deploy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  * executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * executing `multistage:ensure'
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:bgadoci/WODstack.git master"
    command finished in 2244ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:db:symlink'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing `whenever:clear_crontab'
  * executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing `deploy:symlink'
[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing `deploy:restart_workers'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update'
  * executing `newrelic:notice_deployment'
  * executing `deploy:restart'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:restart'
  * executing `whenever:update_crontab'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing `deploy:db:symlink'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing `whenever:clear_crontab'
  * executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing `deploy:symlink'
[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing `deploy:restart_workers'
  * executing `deploy:restart'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:restart'
  * executing `whenever:update_crontab'
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `deploy:cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that deploy:migrations actually runs the whole darn thing. The right one is deploy:migrate in my scenario